# Processing and classifying satellite images using Python

Tags: python, digital-image-processing, image-classification

I wish to process and classify Sentinel2-L2A images using solely Python (Google Colab). Is it possible to do such a thing, and if so, what libraries should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can use the rasterio library to process the images:https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/,
the sentinelsat library to download the images: https://github.com/sentinelsat/ and for classify you can use scikit image https://scikit-image.org/.